# Avoid the ugly image loading effect on pages rendered by ng view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, angularjs

I have a lot of images on my site. To load them and avoid the ugly top to bottom image loading effect I am currently setting the `body` to `display none` and then

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

This seems to work for the homepage. But when I fetch pages, inside ng-view using angular, which also have images in them, the images don't seem to be loaded already and I seem to be getting the ugly top to bottom image loading effect. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Alternative: http://blog.codinghorror.com/progressive-image-rendering/

Comment: @cbuckley Thanks for that but I want to avoid any kind of effect all together and just show the ajax page only when all the images are loaded.

Comment: Btw, when you fetch a page via AJAX, you fetch the HTML, not the image data. Your browser will only then start downloading any assets in that HTML.

Comment: @christian314159 Indeed you are right. Following what you said, I want to show the ajax page to user only when all the assets are downloaded. I can show a loading bar or something till then.

Comment: I would try loading the AJAX response into a jQuery object and binding a load event to that. It will fire once all assets have downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax("url/to/page", {
    success: function(data) {
        $temp = $("<div/>").html(data);
        $temp.on("load", function() {
            // Assume body is already faded out for loading
            // Add HTML to the body
            $("body").html($temp.html());

            // Show content
            $("body").fadeIn(2000);
        });
    }
});
```

This will load the returned HTML into a temporary div and wait for the assets linked within it to load before adding it to the `<body>`.

Comment: Thank you for this. But as I already mentioned in my question, I am using angular.js to fetch pages inside ng-view. I am not really doing the ajax part, angular does it.

Comment: You tagged your question as jQuery. I am sure Angluar gives you something to hook a callback for AJAX calls as jQuery does. Use this success function as that.